# Superset/Celery Beat: Daily Scheduled Reports Failed in some days Need Assistance Understanding Initial Failure

Tags: celery, apache-superset, celerybeat

I've set up Superset with Celery Beat to handle daily scheduled reports. Strangely, between November  22 to December 2 , the scheduled reports didn't run as expected. Surprisingly, they've been working fine since then without any changes. I'm puzzled about the initial failure and seeking insights into what might have caused it. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or could offer guidance on troubleshooting this? Your help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Execution log]

if you check  execution log November 22 to December 2 its not run properly but it  was working fine after that.

Also how can i re-run those reports which was missed to send